# SAS: How to run proc x11 for multiple variables at one time in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a time series data containing about 15 variables by group (district). I am trying to run a pro x11 such that the output will have the 15 variables and its accompanying adjusted values. I am currently using the following code for one variable. My goal is to eventually create a sgpanel of each of the variable by district. I think I would have to find a way produce a dataset that has all the variable along side with its adjusted values. How can this be achieved with prox11?

Data looks like:

```
district  variable1  variable2   variable3 .......variable15  date_new   
gotam          2         7            8              3
```

Code:

```
proc x11 data = all_districts noprint;
monthly additive date = date_new;
id district;
var mean_malaria_rate;
tables a1 d12;
output out = test_all_mal a1 = mean_malaria_rate d12 = adj;run;
```

Comment: is `mean_malaria_rate` one of your `variable<n>` variables ?

Comment: `Transpose` your data, sort the result `by _name_` and use a `by _name_` in your `Proc X11`